# Free Database of Uniform Commercial Code (UCC) Data?

Tags: data-request, download

I am looking for [Uniform Commercial Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Commercial_Code) (UCC) data to download and sift through. I would be most interested in Article 2 and 2A which is sales and leases, respectively. This is also known at UCC-2 data.

Does anyone know where I might find a database of UCC-2 data, by U.S. state, for free?

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of places where you can read the UCC:

- [Sales](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/2)
- [Leases](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/2A)

And other places linked from the bottom of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Commercial_Code#External_links).

It's not completely clear to me if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I am not looking for the law but the data collected by each state.

Comment: what data? could you provide some examples

Comment: Here is an example of the form that is required for the state of Kansas. Other states have their own version of the form but its basically the same information collected. My question is that I am wondering if this information is available, somewhere, openly / free.
https://www.kssos.org/forms/ucc/ucc1.pdf